# Path Not Found error when copying files using wildcard

Tags: vbscript, file-management

Source Code:

```
Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
Dim strSafeDate, strSafeTime, strDateTime

strSafeDate = Right("0" & DatePart("d",Date), 2) & "." & Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2) & "." & DatePart("yyyy",Date)
strSafeTime = Right("0" & Hour(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Minute(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Second(Now), 2)

strDateTime = strSafeDate & " - " & strSafeTime

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objFSO.CopyFile "\\Ilgglafnp02\sapoutput\PRD\SpiceWorksReports\CurrentReportFiles\TicketsRaised(All)\*.*", "\\Ilgglafnp02\sapoutput\PRD\SpiceWorksReports\Archive\TicketsRaised(All)\"& strDateTime & ".xls"
objFSO.DeleteFile "\\Ilgglafnp02\sapoutput\PRD\SpiceWorksReports\CurrentReportFiles\TicketsRaised(All)\*.*"
```

Details:

I'm trying to write a simple script that copies all files from one shared location on a network to another for archiving purposes.

When I specify the name of the origin file like this:

```
objFSO.CopyFile "\\Ilgglafnp02\sapoutput\PRD\SpiceWorksReports\CurrentReportFiles\TicketsRaised(All)\HelloWorld.xls",
```

The file is copied to the Archive folder and renamed to the current date and time - which is correct, and the file in the origin folder is deleted as it should be.

However, when I change this script to try to move all files from this folder, I get the following error message:

```
Script: Reporting.vbs
Line:   16
Char:   1
Error:  Path not found
Code:   800A004C
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

This is confusing me because the `DeleteFile` line uses the same directory path and also uses the "*.*" wildcard, but this gives no errors or issues when the script is run specifying the origin filename.

I know there is `xcopy`, but I'd really like to avoid this as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to copy several source files into only one target .xls file, but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) states

> If source contains wildcard characters or destination ends with a path
>   separator (\), it is assumed that destination is an existing folder in
>   which to copy matching files.

Your source includes wildcards, but your target is not a existing folder, and that is the cause of the error.

You have two options

- first create a folder with the timestamp to copy all the files into it without any renaming
- iterate over the files collection for the source folder, copying each file to a timestamped one in the target.

Comment: Excellent, this is perfect. Feeling pretty stupid now that I know it was that simple of an issue. Thank you.